# how to get user spaces using Webscript in alfresco

Tags: alfresco, web-scripting

i'm working on a small project to get the current user spaces in alfresco. i searched in the few days buts no result.

can any one help me to get the current user spaces using webscript in alfresco.

thanks you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean the user's home folder? In java you can do it like this:

```
NodeRef personNode = personService.getPerson(userName);
NodeRef homeFolderNode = nodeService.getProperty(personNode, ContentModel.PROP_HOMEFOLDER);
```

In javascript you could get it like this:

```
var userhome = companyhome.childByNamePath("User Homes/" + userName);
```

If you're looking for something other than that, please comment.

Comment: thnak you for your answer,but i wanna get all the spaces and content ( like left menu in alfresco)

Comment: the username is not always the corresponding name of the user home. The safest way would be:
var user = people.getPerson(userName);
 
 var user_home = user.properties["cm:homeFolder"];